# How to post Image to facebook using koala gem

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, koala

I am using this code to post images to facebook

```
 def post_to_facebook(facebook_auth)
    graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(facebook_auth.token)
       graph.put_wall_post(self.message, {
      "picture" => self.avatar.url(:thumb),
      "description" => self.message
        })
 end
```

but I am not able to open local images

No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - index5.jpeg

if any one knows solution please let me know

Comment: and this has what to do with PostgreSQL? *Confused*

Comment: i am using pg as database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def post_to_facebook(facebook_auth,image,content)
      begin
         graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(facebook_auth.token)
         graph.put_picture(image,content,{:message => self.message})
         rescue Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed => e  
      end  
end
```